# Read Video from specific folder of SD Card other than /sdcard/Movies folder

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have a created a android program to read videos from any specific folder of sdcard and then display their thumbnails in Grid View.
However my program is working correctly for  Movies folder in sdcard  only.
Its not showing any videos for other folders in sdcard.

I have specified the name of the folder "Movies" at two places in my code.
Once in  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener     and another   in   initVideosId().

Now there is other folders also in my sdcard,  say   sdcard->geovideo

Now when I am specifying   "geovideo"  instead of  "Movies"  then it is showing nothing in my tablet.  Do you have any idea what is the problem.

Anyone please help me to do my task.
Thanks.
Below is my android program

```
package com.vt.soc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    //set constants for MediaStore to query, and show videos
    private final static Uri MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    private final static String _ID = MediaStore.Video.Media._ID;
    private final static String MEDIA_DATA = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA;
    //flag for which one is used for images selection
    private GridView _gallery; 
    private Cursor _cursor;
    private int _columnIndex;
    private int[] _videosId;
    private Uri _contentUri;
    String filename;
    int flag = 0;



    protected Context _context;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _context = getApplicationContext();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //set GridView for gallery
        _gallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.videoGrdVw);
        //set default as external/sdcard uri
        _contentUri = MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        initVideosId();

        //set gallery adapter
        setGalleryAdapter();


    }
    private void setGalleryAdapter() {
        _gallery.setAdapter(new VideoGalleryAdapter(_context));
        _gallery.setOnItemClickListener(_itemClickLis);
        flag = 1;       
    }
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener _itemClickLis = new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unused", "rawtypes" })
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
        {
            // Now we want to actually get the data location of the file
            String [] proj={MEDIA_DATA};
            // We request our cursor again
            _cursor = managedQuery(_contentUri,
                    proj, // Which columns to return
                    MEDIA_DATA + " like ? ",       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                    new String[] {"%Movies%"},       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                    null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
            // We want to get the column index for the data uri
            int count = _cursor.getCount();
            //
            _cursor.moveToFirst();
            //
            _columnIndex = _cursor.getColumnIndex(MEDIA_DATA);
            // Lets move to the selected item in the cursor
            _cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            // And here we get the filename
            filename = _cursor.getString(_columnIndex);
            //*********** You can do anything when you know the file path :-)
            showToast(filename);

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Player.class); 
            i.putExtra("videoPath", filename);
            startActivity(i);


            //
        }
    };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void initVideosId() {
        try
        {
            //Here we set up a string array of the thumbnail ID column we want to get back
            String [] proj={_ID};
            // Now we create the cursor pointing to the external thumbnail store
            _cursor = managedQuery(_contentUri,
                    proj, // Which columns to return
                    MEDIA_DATA + " like ? ",       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                    new String[] {"%Movies%"},       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                    null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
            int count= _cursor.getCount();
            // We now get the column index of the thumbnail id
            _columnIndex = _cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID);
            //initialize 
            _videosId = new int[count];
            //move position to first element
            _cursor.moveToFirst();          
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {           
                int id = _cursor.getInt(_columnIndex);
                //
                _videosId[i]= id;
                //
                _cursor.moveToNext();
                //
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            showToast(ex.getMessage().toString());          
        }

    }
    protected void showToast(String msg)
    {
        Toast.makeText(_context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //
    private class VideoGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        public VideoGalleryAdapter(Context c) 
        {
            _context = c;
        }
        public int getCount() 
        {
            return _videosId.length;
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ImageView imgVw= new ImageView(_context);;
            try
            {
                if(convertView!=null)
                {
                    imgVw= (ImageView) convertView;
                }
                imgVw.setImageBitmap(getImage(_videosId[position]));
                imgVw.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
                imgVw.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("MainActivity:getView()-135: ex " + ex.getClass() +", "+ ex.getMessage());
            }
            return imgVw;
        }

        // Create the thumbnail on the fly
        private Bitmap getImage(int id) {
            Bitmap thumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            return thumb;
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually problem was the user permission in my manifest file.

I hope any one who face the same problem as mine,
will be happy to see my answser.

Actually,   Movies   folder was  in built folder in sdcard
and as I mentioned that I have   my own folder 'geovideo'   in sdcard
Which I was not able to see via my program.
So I need to specify the permission in Manifest   file.

When I added

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

to my manifest.
It's working.
So just simple advice,
When your program is not working think about permission as well.